# Embed an SVG in a bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg

Is there any way to embed an SVG in a Bootstrap 3 popover? I can get the HTML to work in a popover like this:

```
var myText = 'here is some text'

$('#my-element').popover({
  container: 'body',
  content: myText,
  placement: 'right',
  html: true
})
```

What I would really like to do is to programmatically create the SVG inside a function like this:

```
$('#my-element').popover({
  container: 'body',
  content: function() {
    // add a new div, #my-popover-div,   
    // then build an svg here by appending
    // onto the newly created #my-popover-div
  }
  placement: 'right',
  html: true
})
```

Is it possible to create a SVG inside a popover?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define the `content` property as a function that returns a string, DOM node, or jQuery collection. When the function is called, the return value will be appended to the popover element.

#### From the [Boostrap Popover options documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options):

> If a function is given, it will be called with its `this` reference set to the element that the popover is attached to.

Inside that function, you can construct an SVG however you like. In the following example, I construct the SVG from a string. You could alternately return an SVG string for a static SVG, but the advantage of returning a DOM node or jQuery collection is you can dynamically create the SVG content more-easily.

## Working Example ([Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/uW7l7o6O0t)):

```js
$('#my-element').popover({
  container: 'body',
  content: function() {
    //Create our wrapper div (optional).
    var $el = $('<div id="#my-popover-div"></div>');
    //Create the SVG child (can be created more-dynamically).
    $el.append('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="467" height="462" viewBox="0 0 467 462" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">' + 
        '<rect x="80" y="60" width="250" height="250" rx="20" style="fill:#ff0000; stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2px;" />' + 
        '<rect x="140" y="120" width="250" height="250" rx="40" style="fill:#0000ff; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:2px; fill-opacity:0.7;" />' + 
      '</svg>');
    //Return the jQuery collection.
    return $el;
  },
  placement: 'right',
  html: true
});
```

```css
#my-element {
  margin: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="my-element">Click Me!</button>
```

## Screenshot:

[image: svg popover]

Comment: HTML5 supports SVG tags, so you could dynamically create them with your JavaScript function. Should be very easy with jQuery.

And if svg.js is also an option, I think you could create the SVG using JavaScript and let the svg.js library create the SVG string for you. http://svgjs.com/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the html property. In my example below, I'm using a button with a circle svg inside the popover.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/6s8qn70r/)

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Popover</button>
```

JS

```
$('button').each(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        placement: "bottom",
        content: function() {
            //you can create the div before and then append the svg. I'm doing all at once.
var content = '<div id="#my-popover-div"><svg width="50" height="50"><circle r="20" cx="25" cy="25" style="fill: blue"/></svg></div>';
            return content;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**First Example**
**Your HTML**

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover">Dismissible popover</a>
```

**Your Javascript**

```
var text = 'And here\'s some amazing content. It\'s very engaging. Right? An SVG image is added to my popover!';
var svg = '<svg height="150" width="400"><defs><linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" /><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" /></linearGradient></defs><ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" /><text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">SVG</text>Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>';
$('a').popover({
    container: 'body',
    content: function () {
       return text+svg;
    },
    placement: 'right',
    html: true
});
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/fuj4xxx0/

**Second example**

**HTML**

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover">Dismissible popover</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var text = 'And here\'s some amazing content. It\'s very engaging. Right? An SVG image is added to my popover!';
var svg = '<svg height="150" width="400"><defs><linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"><stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" /><stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" /></linearGradient></defs><ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" /><text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">SVG</text>Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg>';
$('a').popover({
    container: 'body',
    content: function () {
        var mysvgdiv=$('<div id="svg_id" style="border:1px solid red;padding:5px"></div>');
       return mysvgdiv.prepend(text).append(svg);
    },
    placement: 'right',
    html: true
});
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/fuj4xxx0/3/